# Can I add Tensorflow Fake Quantization in a Keras sequential model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have searched this for a while, but it seems Keras only has quantization feature after the model is trained. I wish to add Tensorflow fake quantization to my Keras sequential model. According to Tensorflow's doc, I need these two functions to do fake quantization: tf.contrib.quantize.create_training_graph() and tf.contrib.quantize.create_eval_graph().
My question is has anyone managed to add these two functions in a Keras model? If yes, where should these two function be added? For example, before model.compile or after model.fit or somewhere else? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked around by post-training quantization. Since my final goal is to train a mdoel for mobile device, instead of fake quantization during training, I exported keras .h5 file and converted to Tenforflow lite .tflite file directly (with post_training_quantize flag set to true). I tested this on a simple cifar-10 model. The original keras model and the quantized tflite model have very close accuracy (the quantized one a bit lower).

Post-training quantization: https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/post_training_quantization
Convert Keras model to tensorflow lite: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite/toco/g3doc/python_api.md
Used the tf-nightly tensorflow here: https://pypi.org/project/tf-nightly/

If you still want to do fake quantization (because for some model, post-training quantization may give poor accuracy according to Google), the original webpage is down last week. But you can find it from github: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/quantize

**Update**: Turns out post-quantization does not really quantize the model. **During inference, it still uses float32 kernels to do calculations.** Thus, I've switched to quantization-aware training. The accuracy is pretty good for my cifar10 model.

Comment: Hey, do you have example code of quantization aware training with keras? I've been trying to get it working but without much results so far.

Comment: @Deb There is a good example in the tensorflow github. The link is: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/examples/speech_commands    Take a look at the train.py, models.py, and freeze.py. They contain all the necessary parts of quantization aware training.